# Kafka unordered message scenario handling

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have scenario in kafka message processing where i get 3 types of loads:

1. category_create
2. folder_create
3. article_create

for which i make entry in DB

Ideally loads should come in order :
category_create -> folder_create -> article_create, 
because folder always belong to certain category and article always belong to certain folder. For folder_create to process category of the folder should have already been received as kafka message. However there are certain cases where folder_create load comes milliseconds before category_create.

What can i do in spring boot to wait for milliseconds in case of folder_create to allow category_create to process and then process folder_create.

Tried using @Retry and @Recover in spring boot but i guess this does not fit in this scenario.

Comment: oder of message can not be achieved using kafka, may be try to store them in cache first and then save it to database

Answer (score 0):

Consumer cannot handle the message ordering , it should be handled at producer end

Answer (score 0):

Consumers cannot guarantee the order, it should be done by producer.

We had something similar case, we created a temporary table in DB to store the message until we receive the required message. Then process the record from DB and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The consumer is guaranteed to consume the message in append order. 
In your case, you should consider secure the Producer is sending the message in order. To achieve that will be better let "max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1","acks=all" another is "enable.idempotence=true". But those may bite you on throughput.